# Limit Clause Neo4jClient

Tags: neo4jclient

I am trying to implement the Limit clause in Cypher in Neo4jClient but it doe not seem to be supported (?).

I thought I saw some [test cases](http://hg.readify.net/neo4jclient/src/585551d9b71dc08ee8278d78838fe01acb0b245d/Test/Cypher/CypherFluentQueryLimitTests.cs) / other documents refer to it but I can't seem to find it in my intellisense.

Is there a work around to limit results to only top 5? I have 5000+ results and results are painfully slow.

I am using Neo4jClient version 1.0.0.572. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tests that you pointed to clearly indicate that it exists, and works, and is supported, and tested.

Without having posted your query, I can only guess at the problem.

The `Limit` method only shows up after you've called `Return`, because [it's defined on](http://hg.readify.net/neo4jclient/src/bc331d266ae415c00800434165535dcf5efad6f0/Neo4jClient/Cypher/ICypherFluentQuery%60TResult.cs?at=default) `ICypherFluentQuery<TResults>`, not `ICypherFluentQuery`.

Comment: You the man. Basically my Cypher query had Limit after the orderby clause so I was trying to replicate that as is. But now I changed it after returns and it works.

Comment: I'm confused by that. You well and truly are allowed to do .Return().OrderBy().Limit(). OrderBy returns the typed fluent interface as well, and thus has the Limit signature on it.

Comment: I just confirmed it again. Works after Return but not after Results or OrderByDescending Clause. I can send you screen shot or code if you'd like.

Comment: Here is the error if I put it after OrderBy Error 5 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'Limit' and no extension method 'Limit' accepting a first argument of type. 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: The code btw is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558103/incorrect-sort-order-with-neo4jclient-cypher-query

Comment: Ah, once you call .Results, you are no longer writing a Neo4j query. You are writing a LINQ-to-Objects query. You should put as much as you can before the Results call, so that it happens on the Neo4j server.